# Mux Router doesn't work in Dockerized golang project

Tags: docker, rest, go, gorilla, mux

I tested locally and it works totally fine on my local.
I can get responses from POST, GET methods.

But when I dockerize the application and try to test the same endpoints, I get nothing.
I have tried all the suggestions herein Stackoverflow. So I will paste my Dockerfile and Makefile to get your opinions on it.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.16.5 AS build-env

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y locales \
                          make \
                          xz-utils \
                          zip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

FROM build-env AS builder
WORKDIR /build
COPY . .
RUN set -x \
    && make

FROM debian:buster AS runner

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y ca-certificates \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && update-ca-certificates

COPY --from=builder /build/bin/* .
CMD ["./applicaitonx"]
```

and my Makefile:

```
build:
    go build -o bin/applicaitonx -v -buildmode=exe .
```

to be able to build the docker, I'm using the following command;

```
docker build -t app .
```

and then I run it.

I see that the application is running and listenandserve doesn't throw an error at all. BUT mux is not routing at all.
It says it listens but it doesn't.
I will also copy the following part in `main.go`

```
srv := &http.Server{
    Handler: router,
    Addr: ":" + os.Getenv("PORT"),
}

if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
}
```

I inspect all the env variables, so `os.GetEnv("PORT")` doesn't return null. I'm sure about it.
I wrote some debug comments, and as far as I see codes doesn't go even that debug comments. So it doesn't print anything at all.

Comment: How do you call that endpoint?

Comment: I just do it using Postman, but I'm getting socket hang up. I even tried with curl but got empty response from server. And when I look at the logs, I see that it doesn't hit the debug comments. Mux doesn't work at all.

Comment: What does `curl -v` report on your endpoints?

Comment: What is the URL you're calling?

Comment: Can you please attach the docker image run command as well, i think port mapping isn't in place, due to which you might not able to reach to the application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible that the port you are using inside the container is not exposed to outside world, hence you can't reach them. Try adding `-p` flag like below:

```
docker run -p P1:P2
```

P1 = TCP port

P2 = Container port

Please refer: [this doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose)